# How to position text at the bottom of a triangle div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a following div:

```css
div {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px; 
  border-left:  126px solid transparent;
  border-right:  126px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:  126px solid #D30000;
  position: relative;
  left: 55%;
  top: 40px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div>Triangle</div>
```

The following align text on the triangle like this :

```
                    _Triangle_
                   /          \
                  /            \
                 /              \
                /                \
               /________________  \
```

What I am trying to accomplish is this :

```
                       /\
                      /  \
                     /    \
                    /      \
                   /        \
                  / Triangle \
```

How to I push the text to the bottom of a triangle div without having to wrap it in a tag? It is important for me to use position: relative; since absolute did not work. However, even if I remove position:relative; the text still doesn't go to the bottom of a div. It stays on top where the top angle of the triangle gets cut off and makes the shape look like a trapezoid.

Comment: The text **should** be in a text tag at the least anyway. Text nodes are the worst.

Comment: I am trying to accomplish this without using any tags

Comment: Since the triangle is only made of borders you may have to re-think your structure/approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a pseudo element to make the triangle.

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  width: 126px;
  margin: 126px auto;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 126px solid transparent;
  border-right: 126px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 126px solid #D30000;
}
```

```html
<div>Triangle</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with additional SPAN inside DIV and before pseudo class that is used for drawing triangle. I use SPAN to position text to the bottom of DIV.

```css
div{
    width: 252px;
    height: 126px;
    position: absolute;
}
div>span{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
div:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    border-width: 126px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent #D30000  transparent;
    display: block;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div><span>Triangle</span></div>
```

I tried it in chroma and IE.